# How can I fix blurry map thumbnails?

Tags: starcraft-2

A few of the map thumbnails have somehow become distorted. How can I fix it? I'd rather not reinstall the entire game.

[image: Pixelated map thumbnail]

Comment: Did you turn down texture quality?

Comment: @StrixVaria Every single graphics setting is at its highest. Most of the thumbnails are fine, so I don't think this is related to my configuration.

Comment: I think this is related to the downloading of maps process but I'm not 100%

Comment: I have this problem too - happened after the v1.1 patch.

Comment: Do we know where the maps are stored? It might help to delete them, forcing them to redownloaded.

Comment: Happened to me too on this specific map (although I remember it well enough by now :)

Comment: Happened to me too on the same exact map.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it's the graphics card driver. Update to a newer version, if available, or try an older one.